# Windows forms auto size in c#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, resize, resolution

I am developing a windows forms application using c#. It has mdi parent form and child forms.
My developing environment resolution is 1366 * 768.
But I want to develop this application to fit any resolution how can i do this ? e.g (1024 * 768 etc.)

At the moment i have used following lines in the form load event of mdi parent.

```
 this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
 this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: the problem was form is fit into screen size but controls are not fitting according to form size.

Comment: If you can't support layout that works on any windows size (try resizing Visual Studio's window to see what that could look like) then you'll need to design for the smallest size you are willing to support.  If you find out about this too late then you can set the form's AutoSize property to True.  That won't impress anybody but at least it is still usable.

Comment: Please can you explain it more ?, Currently I have a project which was developed earlier. Now I want to add this to the exiting project no to new one (auto sizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having, with the controls not fitting may be solved by Anchoring or docking the controls. In this way you can decide when the form is made smaller, what happens to the children. Here are some tutorials that you may find useful:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Designing_Forms_in_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Studio
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6964/0/page/3
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908

Comment: thank you replying without anchor and dock properties is there any other way ?